# Getting following errors Text too small to read, Clickable elements too close together, Content wider than screen

Tags: google-search-console, html, mobile

I am getting the following errors in the GSC in mobile usability area.
 1. Text too small to read
 2. Clickable elements too close together
 3. Content wider than screen

I got the same error in the last month(for another page) and it fixed automatically. Did any faced similar issue previously?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is looking to poll users rather than solve a specific problem.

Comment: I don't know how you marked it as **off-topic**?

Comment: Sites on the Stack Exchange network, with a few exceptions, require questions that can have a "right answer". Questions that poll users, such as asking if others have faced the same issue, do not fall into that category. Questions like this are better suited for [chat].